# 3ds Max Biped Scale Restriction

Tags: 3d-meshes, 3dsmax, skeletal-animation

I have a 3D Model under 3ds Max and I'm trying to integrate a biped skeleton. But when I start to adjust the pelvis or any other bone I can't scale it.

I don't know why, and this is driving me crazy. If someone can help it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to press the figure mode in order to adjust the biped bones. It is the only way to scale the bones of the biped.

After that if you want to animate or make poses of the biped, you must be out of the figure mode, so switch if off before.